# sh scripting: [ program ] && [ program ] vs. if [ program ] then [ program ]

Tags: sh, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
# step through the jobs and execute them one by one
while IFS= read -r job
do
    [ -n "$job" ] && (
        script=$JOBDIR/$job.sh
        ( [ -x $script ] && /bin/sh $script ) || echo `date +%Y-%m-%d` `date +%H:%M:%S` "$script does not exist" >> $JOBFAILS
    )
done < $JOBLIST
```

Which could (AFAIK) also be written as:

```
# step through the jobs and execute them one by one
while IFS= read -r job
do
    if [ -n "$job" ] then
        script=$JOBDIR/$job.sh
        if [ -x $script ] then
            /bin/sh $script || echo `date +%Y-%m-%d` `date +%H:%M:%S` "$script does not exist" >> $JOBFAILS
        fi
    fi
done < $JOBLIST
```

The variables are references to text files or folders that exist.

As far as I know, the ( ) creates a subshell. Does this mean that everything in brackets runs in a different process? What would be the performance impact of that?
What other differences or gotchas should I be aware of?

PS: If someone could edit the title to be more "search friendly", I'd appreciate it. It's the best description that I could come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `( command )` runs `command` in a subshell. This requires forking a new process, which is less efficient and more resource intensive than running the command in the current shell. The difference may or may not be negligible, depending on how many times your code forks.

You are also correct that you can rewrite

```
[ expr ] && command
```

as

```
if [ expr ]; then
    command
fi
```

(note that if you put `then` on the same line as `if`, you need to add a semicolon)

I would recommend changing your code to get rid of the unnecessary subshell invocations. Not only are they less efficient than `if...then`, they also make the code harder to read and debug, in my opinion.

As an aside, depending on which version of which shell you're using, `[` may or may not be a shell builtin. If you're running an old version of the Bourne shell, for example, `[` may actually invoke the external program `/bin/[` (which is usually just an alias for `/bin/test`). This spawns yet another process with its associated overhead. If you're using a modern shell, however, you don't need to worry about this, since as far as I know, all modern shells implement a built-in `[` command.